# Translate this R geometric problem using numpy random geometric

Tags: r, numpy

How can I translate this **geometric law** problem to numpy ?

**Products produced by a machine has a 3% defective rate.
What is the probability that the first defective oc-curs in the fifth item inspected?**

> P(X= 5) =P(1st 4 non-defective )P( 5th defective)=(0.974)(0.03)
>
> In R > dgeom (x= 4, prob = .03)[1] 0.02655878T
>
> The convention in R is to record X as the number of failures that occur
>   before the first success.

Is this my numpy code ok ? :

```
result = np.random.geometric(p=0.03, size=1000)
print(result);

result =  (result == 5).sum() / 1000.
print(result * 1000,"%");
```

I get 17 % as a result with numpy , is it ok ? Seem wrong because there is only 3% defect rate.

This is the numpy result Array :

```
""" [ 31  20  37   9  47  31  22   7  44  15  52  15   4  14  36  45  26  27
   9  48  30   5   7  17   7  24 121  22  23  49   2  26  25   8   4   5
   3  27  70  71   3   1  19  22 103  18  14  20  34  45   8 169  11  63
  29  71  30  79  75  19  56   9   5   8  15  44   8  12  40  29  46   2
 144  69  65   1   4  90  20 187 100  52  46  76   3 105  12 110  31   3
 113  18   6  15 127  22   6   7   3  18 123  41  69 104  13  18   2   8
  52  35  54  27  74  22  31  27   3  15  21  26  13   3  32  10 131  20
```

I guess that 31 is the number of integrity checks before a failure .... 20 , 37 etc ...

Comment: They say ''The convention in R is to recordX as the number of failures that occur before the first success."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
np.random.seed(1)
tests = np.random.choice([0,1], size=(1000,5), p=[0.7,0.3])

((np.argmax(tests, axis=1) == 4) & tests[:,4]==1).mean()
# 0.073
```

Comment: Thank you, but it comes from a geometric law book, do you think I can use numpy.random.geometric() to calculate it ?

Comment: Ah, yes. I'm not that familiar with `geometric` but this would do `(np.random.geometric(0.3, size=1000)==5).mean()`.

Comment: Thanks , I have just discovered https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.geom.html too .

Comment: 1000 is rather small. But yes, around that.